# LinearPercentIndicator is reseting animation every time that percentage vaue is changed

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I'm using the Linear Percent Indicator for a progress bar. Each time this percentage value changes, the animation goes from 0 to the current progress number. I want the animation to go from the last progress number to the current progress number.

without the animation, the bar makes a correct "jump" (from the last number to the current one), but the animation is needed.

Gif of how the problem is:

[image]

how it should be:

[image]

My code:

```
Consumer<ProgressBarProvider>(
 builder: (BuildContext context, value, Widget? child) {
   return LinearPercentBar:
      Center(
         child: LinearPercentIndicator(
              animation: true,
              progressColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(217, 217, 217, 1),
              percent: value.getPercentProgress,
              lineHeight: 15,
              linearStrokeCap: LinearStrokeCap.roundAll,
              barRadius: Radius.circular(30),
              restartAnimation: false,
       )
   );
}
```

I'm using the Provider library to manage the state of the percentage and the number of items variables.

I want to know how do I leave the animation from one number to the next without the animation going all the way to the current number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve! I only needed add the parameter

```
animateFromLastPercent: true,
```

into LinearPercentIndicator.
It was like this:

```
LinearPercentIndicator(
      animation: true,
      animationDuration: 500,
      animateFromLastPercent: true,
      progressColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(217, 217, 217, 1),
      percent: value.getPercentProgress,
      lineHeight: 15,
      linearStrokeCap: LinearStrokeCap.roundAll,
      barRadius: Radius.circular(30),
      restartAnimation: false,
)
```